# AngularJS using ng-repeat value outside of repeat block and in script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularJS and am struggling with an issue. I've searched extensively for an answer and tried a few dirty hacks as well, but I still cannot resolve the issue.

I have a ng-repeat directive which get displays data from a my controller (from a factory). However one of the items in the ng-repeat block is a javascript progress bar which requires the value to be set in javascript... This value needs to be extracted from the ng-repeat dataset.

At the moment there is a script block included in the HTML where the value is to be set (I am sure this is not the recommended way to achieve this and I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction as far as how to achieve this with best practice). My problem is that I can't use an angular expression in the script block so I do not know how to set the value, I believe all the code necessary is below:

HTML from the partial:

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="memberDetail in memberDetails" ng-cloak>
        <div id="dashboard-left" class="span12">
            <h4 class="widgettitle">{{memberDetail.MemberName}}</h4>
                <div class="widgetcontent nopadding">
                    <ul class="commentlist">
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/saica-logo.jpg" alt="" class="pull-left" />
                            <div class="comment-info">
                                <div style="height: 150px">                                               
                                    <span style="position: absolute;"><h5>Cycle</h5></span><div id="progressBar1" class="default"><div></div></div><h5 style="float: right; margin-top: -30px">3yr Cycle</h5>
                                    <span style="position: absolute;"><h5>Ver</h5></span><div data-percent=50 id="progressBar2" class="default1"><div></div></div><h5 style="float: right; margin-top: -30px">60 Hours</h5>
                                    <span style="position: absolute;"><h5>NonVer</h5></span><div id="progressBar3" class="default2"><div></div></div><h5 style="float: right; margin-top: -30px">60 Hours</h5>
                              <div id="PBValue" style="">{{memberDetail.verPercent}}</div>                                                               
                                </div>                       
                    <script>
                        //The progress bar values need to be set here.                        
                        progressBar(70, $('#progressBar1'));
                        progressBar(70, $('#progressBar2')); //memberDetail.verPercent
                        progressBar(40, $('#progressBar3')); //memberDetail.NonVerPercent
                    </script>
                    <span  style="float: left; margin-top: -15px; ">
                        <h6><em>*You need {{60 - memberDetail.VerHours}} CPD hours over the next 3 months  </em></h6> 
                        <h6><em>*You need {{60 - memberDetail.NonVerHours}} hours of learning 3 months</em></h6>                                                           
                    </span><br>
                    <span  style="float: right; margin-top: -30px; ">
                        <button id="opendialog" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded">Log Verifiable CPD</button>
                        <button id="opendialog" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded">Log non-verifiable CPD</button>
                        <button id="opendialog" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded">Get SAICA CPD</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                    </li>                                                  
                </ul>
            </div>                                                                      
    </div><!--span12-->       
</div><!--row-fluid-->
```

I've added a comment to show where the progress bar values need to be set as well as what the values would be from the ng-repeat dataset.

My controller:

```
memberDetailsApp.controller('ctrlrMemberDetails', function($scope, fctryMemberDetails)
{       
fctryMemberDetails.getMemberDetails(function(details)
{
    $scope.memberDetails = details;
});
});
```

Here is the factory:

```
memberDetailsApp.factory('fctryMemberDetails',['$http', function($http)
{               
var MemberDetailsFactory = {};

MemberDetailsFactory.getMemberDetails = function(successcb)
{                                                   
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/memberDetails.json'})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {                                                                   
        successcb(data);    
        console.log(data);              
    })                      
};              
return MemberDetailsFactory;
}]);
```

If required here is the contents of the json file:

```
[
 {
    "MemberName":"SAICA",
    "VerHours":"24",
    "verPercent":"60",
    "NonVerHours":"12",
    "NonVerPercent":"30"
 },
 {
    "MemberName":"IRBA",
    "VerHours":"30",
    "verPercent":"75",
    "NonVerHours":"40",
    "NonVerPercent":"100"
 }
]
```

Could someone please show me how to set the progress bar values with the data in the ng-repeat dataset? I would also appreciate it if someone could show me the correct way to achieve this (assuming the script block should be removed from the html of the partial).

Many thanks, any help will be greatly appreciated.
Ed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand you, but this might give you a direction:

1. You can give the id attribute value from angular's scope like this:

   ```
   <div id='{{valueFromScope}}' ..
   ```

2.You can write a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that manipulates the dom with jquery or whatever you choose.

Comment: Hi MichaeLo. Thanks for the answer. Im clear on the angular expression but im trying to make use of it inside of a script block. The answer you provided is for an HTML tag, when you try to reference an angular expression in javascript you get an error caused by the {{}}. Hope that makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? it is the opposite of the whole point of angular's binding. You can do by using a directive, and within manipulate the dom using Jquery or whatever you want, that will give you the syntax you are trying to force. Hey, you can even do so without a directive with plain jquery. But again, both options are a bad practice unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Hi MichaelLo thanks for another answer. My progressbar needs the value set in JS. I dont know enough to be able to set it at this point. I cant use an angular expression in the script block so I cannot work out how to set it. Even if I moved this to the controller and tried to manipulate the DOM, I dont know how many progressbars there will be (as theyre created by the ng-repeat dynamically) and I dont know IDs of the progressbars AND I dont know how to isolate the values relevant to each progressbar from the ng-repeat dataset (memberDetails as per my code).

Comment: What does "I cant use an angular expression in the script block so I cannot work out how to set it" means? You cannot use angular {{}} brackets in you code?

Comment: An angular expression {{something.value}} only works in an HTML tag, it doesnt work in Javascript. If you take a look at my code attached youll see in my partial that after the progress bar is defined in HTML theres a script tag opened and the value is set inside the script block. But the curly braces are not allowed inside the script tag so {{memberDetails.verPercent}} breaks the application.

Comment: Hi MichaelLo. If you look at the code i attached in the question, youll see a progress bar which is inside of a ng-repeat directive. The value of the progress bar needs to be set via javascript and the value needs to come from Angular (memberDetails in this case) but when i try and reference the value in the javascript block {{memberDetails.verPercent}} it breaks. So i need to either know how to reference an angular expression in javascript or know where else i can set this value.

Comment: I don't see the progressBar. How will this affect          progressBar(70, $('#progressBar1')); ?

Comment: That is it exactly, basically i am trying to replace 70 with the value which comes from memberDetails. So i tried to insert {{memberDetails.verPercent}} in place of 70, but this results in an error as the expression isnt recognised in javascript (only in html tags in that form). Is there another way to reference angular expressions that would work inside a script tag?

Comment: Why can't you do it inside the your controller? (p.s it is a really bad practice, you should actually write a directive)

Comment: Id love to do it in the controller but i dont know how to. Can I access memberDetail inside the controller? (The ng-repeat dataset) how will i know which iteration the ng-repeat is on at the time? And how would i isolate that array?

Comment: Still, not sure I know what you mean. What you can do, is create an object that contains both memberDetails and progressBar, and iterate over it in the ng-repeat.{memberDetails : 'A', progressBar: 70}. That will give you what you wrote.